# Unable to create a sub key in the registry as access is denied on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry, windows-10

We have had a piece of software in use for several years and just recently we have started receiving reports of issues.  Investigating the reported issues revealed they are being caused because the software is no longer able to create a sub key in the registry instead it receives an access is denied error.  The one common denominator between all users is that they are using Windows 10.

On windows 10 64 bit the software attempts to create the sub key:

```
HKU\{SID}\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\{OUR_KEY}\{SUB_KEY}
```

On windows 10 32 bit the software attempts to create the sub key:

```
HKU\{SID}\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\{OUR_KEY}\{SUB_KEY}
```

Our key exists in the registry; the software runs with administrator privileges and executes the following code:

```
ORegistry
ORegistry::CreateSubKey( const OString& szSubKeyName )
{
ORegistry result( NULL );

if( m_hKey != NULL )
{
    HKEY hRes;
    wchar_t *wstr = szSubKeyName.toWChars();
    LONG lRes = RegCreateKeyEx( m_hKey, wstr, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, mSamDesired | KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hRes, NULL );
    delete [] wstr;
    if( lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        result = hRes;
    }
    else
    {
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
        FormatMessage( 
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | 
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL,
            lRes,
            0, // Default language
            (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
            0,
            NULL 
        );
        // Process any inserts in lpMsgBuf.
        // ...
        // Display the string.
        ODebugOutput::log(&OString("Registry CreateSubKey Error: Subkey (%s) and windows error (%s)"), &szSubKeyName, &OString((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf));
        //MessageBox( NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf, L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION );
        // Free the buffer.
        LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );
    }
}

return result;
```

We are unable to reproduce this issue so if no solution is known then reproduction steps would also be helpful.

Thanks for your help and time in advance.

Comment: No @MichaelWalz we are writing to HKEY_USERS.

Comment: OK, I got that.  BTW "Thank you for your time..." and similar comments in questions are useless on stackoverflow. They are very often edited out by members of the community.

Comment: Okay thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Does this link help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530198.aspx ?

Comment: It might do, I'll read over it. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing in that article that sheds light on why it has stopped working in Windows 10.

Comment: Confirm the problem occurs on both 64 bit and 32 bit versions. Could you give us some details about why you are trying deliberately to the "VirtualStore" subkeys ?

Comment: I can confirm that it occurs on both 64 bit and 32 bit versions of Windows 10.  Not that much unfortunately. It has something to do with a legacy issue I believe, making various incarnations of the software all work together, but it was written before my time.

Comment: Do you have an [app manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx) in your software ?

Comment: Yeah we have one.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`
    `<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">`
   `<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">`
    `<security>`
      `<requestedPrivileges>`
        `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>`
      `</requestedPrivileges>`
    `</security>`
  `</trustInfo>`
`</assembly>`

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue so would love to know how to deal with this.  My issue is we can't even read the key and the app is being installed with ClickOnce.